# How to put a product in a specific category magento 1.5

Tags: cron

So I have a question, I'm doing a Cron Job for magento where evaluates the date that the administrator puts in one attribute and the category where the product it's going in another attribute(drop-down list), and when the Cron Jobs execute it has to put that product in that specific category that was set on the attribute.

So far I have

```
   //gets actual date
   $date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();    
   $collection->addfieldtofilter('news_from_date', array(array('to' => $date)));
   foreach($collection as $product) {
      //here it should put the product in the specific category
   }
```

I hope you guys can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
   $targetCategoryId = "12";
   foreach($collection as $product) {
       $currentCategories = explode(',',$product->getCategoryIds());
       $currentCategories[] = $targetCategoryId; // add to the array
       $product->setCategoryIds(join(',',$currentCategories)); // join with commas and set to product

       $product->save();
   }
```

Comment: perfect!! but its work better with
array_push($currentCategories, $targetCategoryId);

Comment: I'm always willing to learn... tell me how that works better?

Comment: It's better only if you need to append multiple values to the array. Where a single item is being added it is better to use $array[] = because there is no overhead of calling a function. For reference: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php